# hyperlink mailto em botão

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um hyperlink em HTML para enviar um mail atraves do mailto: 
`<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>`

O problema é que no codigo fonte é possivel visualisar o mail. Como posso alterar para um botão para não se ver o mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução possível é utilizar **Javascript**:

```js
document.getElementById('sendmail').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = 'mailto:email@gmail.com';
});
```

```html
<button id="sendmail">Send</button>
```

A mesma coisa com **jQuery**:

```js
$('#sendmail').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = 'mailto:email@gmail.com';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sendmail">Send</button>
```

Agora, se o problema é não exibir o e-mail no código fonte, a solução é fazer uma solicitação via AJAX:

**Arquivo PHP:**

```
<?php

   if($logado)
      exit(json_encode('email'=>'email@gmail.com');
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#sendmail').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'email.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        document.location.href = 'mailto:' + data.email;
      }
    });
});
```

Assim o e-mail não ficará visível no fonte, mas nada impede o usuário de acessar a página `email.php` e visualizar o e-mail. Você pode fazer verificações de segurança, mas seria sem sentido, pois apartir do momento o usuário clicar no botão, ele terá acesso ao e-mail. Isso pode ser uma boa solução contra robôs de spam, apenas isso.

Answer (score 2):

Em `Javascript` e `HTML`, as informações estarão disponíveis para serem visualizadas via código-fonte. Seria preciso usar alguma outra linguagem (`PHP`, por exemplo), e passar as informações via POST.

Answer (score 2):

Só não entendi o porque do sigilo, quando o usuário clicar irá abrir o gerenciador de email padrão com o email, mas segue um código para que ao passar o mouse sob o botão o link não apareça

```
<form action="mailto:youraddr@domain.tld" method="GET">
    <input name="subject" type="text" />
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**Fonte de referencia:**

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627093/3130590

É possível **disparar** email usando o **phpMailer** https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

- Nesse caso o código fonte ficaria escondido e o sigilo do email seria preservado.

Answer (score 1):

como o Sneeps apontou muito bem, quando o usuário clicar ele irá ver o email.

Mas acredito que o seu problema não é expor o seu email para um usuario da pagina, mas para Bots que fazem a coleta de email para envio de spam.

Neste caso você pode confundir estes bots embaralhando um pouco as coisas. Uma forma de se fazer isto é transformar o email em uma string de base64, e para isto podemos usar as seguintes funções

```
var encodeBase64 = function (string) {
    var bytes = string.split("").map(function (char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    return btoa(bytes);
}

var decodeBase64 = function (base64) {
    var bytes = atob(base64).split(",").map(function (number) {
        return parseInt(number);
    });
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes)
}
```

abaixo segue um exemplo do encode do seu email:

```js
var encodeBase64 = function (string) {
    var bytes = string.split("").map(function (char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    return btoa(bytes);
}

document.getElementById("base64Prefixo").textContent = encodeBase64("mailto:");
document.getElementById("base64Email").textContent = encodeBase64("someone@example.com");
```

```html
<label id="base64Prefixo" ></label>
<label id="base64Email" ></label>
```

agora um segundo exemplo com um link para envio do email, note que coloquei a string base64 que acabamos de obter como uma data custom.

```js
var prefixo = "MTA5LDk3LDEwNSwxMDgsMTE2LDExMSw1OA=="
var inputsEmail = document.querySelectorAll("[data-email]");

var decodeBase64 = function (base64) {
  var bytes = atob(base64).split(",").map(function (number) {
    return parseInt(number);
  });
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes)
}

var sendEmail = function (event) {
  location.href = decodeBase64(prefixo) + decodeBase64(this.dataset.email);
}

inputsEmail = [].slice.apply(inputsEmail);
inputsEmail.forEach(function (inputEmail) { 
  inputEmail.addEventListener("click", sendEmail)
});
```

```html
<a id="sendMail" href="#" data-email="MTE1LDExMSwxMDksMTAxLDExMSwxMTAsMTAxLDY0LDEwMSwxMjAsOTcsMTA5LDExMiwxMDgsMTAxLDQ2LDk5LDExMSwxMDk=" >Enviar Email</a>
```